# Multiple html files like index.html in Ember.JS

Tags: html, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to develop an ember app, where I do not one single html file(index.html) to be the parent html for all my routes.

I want to maintain separate html files with  tag and  tag like:

- dashboard.html
- account.html

which will again have routes and would want to use components inside them.
I do not get a solution in Ember documentation or anywhere else, any other html file other than index.html can be mapped in ember.

Please help.

Comment: tl;dr extract common functionality into addons and setup different apps for each

Comment: Or use one app and two different root routes and nest everything in them.